# Checking variables' existence using Stata

Tags: loops, capture, stata

I have already asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16884421/does-stata-have-any-try-and-catch-mechanism-similar-to-java) how to check for a variable's existence. Nick Cox answered it. Then I tried to modify the answer and to use a `foreach` loop, but it did not work:

```
foreach var in var1 var2 var3 {
capture su `var', meanonly
if _rc == 0 {
local varMean = r(mean)
local varMin = r(min)
local varMax = r(max)
}
else display `var' "DOES NOT EXIST"
}
```

I also tried to use `of` instead of `in`...still no result. I get a message  `var2 not found` and it stops executing. Does `capture` have to prefix the `foreach`? I tried that...did not work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is slightly subtle.

Given that `var2` does not exist, Stata is still being instructed (within the `else` branch) to

```
 display `var' "DOES NOT EXIST"
```

which is to be interpreted as

```
 display var2 "DOES NOT EXIST"
```

So, it first sees

```
 display var2
```

which it is predisposed to interpret as

```
 display var2[1]
```

-- the value in the first observation -- but as said `var2` does not exist, and Stata complains.

What you want is to display the name `var2`, not its contents (which, once more, do not exist), and the fix is simply

```
 else display "`var' DOES NOT EXIST"
```

The position of the double quote delimiter is crucial, to enforce `display` of the name of the thing that does not exist. Names of things that do not exist are just arbitrary text, and Stata has no problem with such text.

In short, when fed to `display`

```
  "`macro'"
```

is a string to be displayed, but

```
 `macro'
```

is the name of a variable or scalar to be displayed, or otherwise a macro with defined content to be displayed.

By the way, your loop just overwrites the previous set of stored results, but presumably you will get to that in due course.